# node-gyp and contextify - The builds tools for v140 (Platform Toolset = 'v140') cannot be found

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, contextify

I have a project that depends on `d3` version `3.5.3` and that depends on `contextify`. When that's running through `node-gyp` it's blowing up. Generally I've been able to fix this by specifying the `msvs_version=2015`, but that didn't work. So, I performed the following:

1. Modified my installation of VS 2015 and installed **everything**, which would have then included `Common Tools for Visual C++`.
2. Executed `npm install -g windows-build-tools`.
3. Executed `npm config set msvs_version 2015`

Even with those steps I'm still getting this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(44,5):
error MSB8020: The builds tools for v140 (Platform T oolset = 'v140') cannot be found.
To build using the v140 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution,
and then select  "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v140 to build using the v140 build tools.
```

The interesting part to me is that it's trying to find these tools in `v110`; I'm just not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by executed `npm install` inside of the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt.